# How do I control what form fields get submitted with jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a search form that when it gets submitted, it goes to someone elses search site. In my form i'm giving users options to choose from. For example, choose to search my site, or external site. They get to choose by selecting radio buttons.

Here's my problem: when searching the external site, because it's also submitting the radio button in the query, the search doesn't work. It's expecting `?SEARCH=Air+Jordan` but instead is getting `?inlineRadioOptions=Catalog&SEARCH=Air+Jordan`. This throws an error on the external site.

Is there a way I can submit this without the radio button? Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
<form name="catsearchform37675" id="sForm" method="post" action="">
<div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="Catalog" onclick="$('.search_textField').attr({name:'searcharg',id:'searcharg'});$('#searchtype').val('t');$('#sForm').attr({action:'http://www.searchlocal.com/ch~S17/X',target:'_blank',method:'GET'});$('#hiddenField').append('<input type=\'hidden\' name=\'searchtype\' id=\'searchtype\' value=\'t\' />');" /> Catalog
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="Website" onclick="$('.search_textField').attr({name:'CAT_Search',id:'CAT_Search'});$('#sForm').attr({action:'/Default.aspx?SiteSearchID=2960&amp;ID=/search-results',target:'self',method:'POST'});" checked="checked" /> Website
</label>
</div>
<div id="hiddenField"></div>
<div class="clearfix"><input type="text" id="CAT_Search" name="CAT_Search" placeholder="Search" hidefocus="true" style="outline: none medium;" class="search_textField" /> <input type="submit" class="search-btn" value="Search" /></div>
</form>
```

Comment: please add ajax call here

Comment: Just move the `inlineRadioOptions` controls out of the form

Comment: simply use javascript to disable any field that you do not wish to submit

Comment: Do you need the `name` attribute on the radio button?

Comment: Agree with @dave why not just move them out the form

Comment: @DavidDomain Radio buttons need names because that's how the browser determines how they're grouped.

Comment: DUH!!!! Can't believe i didn't think of that. Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you must move the radio buttons out of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event "onsubmit" to form and disable the radio inputs before submit:

```
<form onsubmit="$('input[name=inlineRadioOptions]').prop('disabled',true);return true;" name="catsearchform37675"
  id="sForm" method="post" action="">
<div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="Catalog"
               onclick="$('.search_textField').attr({name:'searcharg',id:'searcharg'});$('#searchtype').val('t');$('#sForm').attr({action:'http://www.searchlocal.com/ch~S17/X',target:'_blank',method:'GET'});$('#hiddenField').append('<input type=\'hidden\' name=\'searchtype\' id=\'searchtype\' value=\'t\' />');"/>
        Catalog
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="Website"
               onclick="$('.search_textField').attr({name:'CAT_Search',id:'CAT_Search'});$('#sForm').attr({action:'/Default.aspx?SiteSearchID=2960&amp;ID=/search-results',target:'self',method:'POST'});"
               checked="checked"/> Website
    </label>
</div>
<div id="hiddenField"></div>
<div class="clearfix"><input type="text" id="CAT_Search" name="CAT_Search" placeholder="Search" hidefocus="true"
                             style="outline: none medium;" class="search_textField"/> <input type="submit"
                                                                                             class="search-btn"
                                                                                             value="Search"/></div>
```

Here you have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/885xv2w8/2/)